# How to get id field from http xml response in power automate

Tags: xmlhttprequest, pdf-generation, power-automate

How to get id field from http xml response in power automate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServiceResponse xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://test.qg.apps.test.com/qps/xsd/3.0/was/report.xsd">
  <responseCode>SUCCESS</responseCode>
  <count>1</count>
  <data>
    <Report>
      <id>3505012</id>
    </Report>
  </data>
</ServiceResponse>
```

how can i get outcome 3505012 in result

tried below
@{slice(outputs('createreportxml'), add(nthIndexOf(outputs('createreportxml'), '>', 9), 1), nthIndexOf(outputs('createreportxml'), '<', 10))}

as well as below
xpath(xml(outputs('@{outputs('createreportxml')}'))), 'string(/ServiceResponse/data/Report/id/text())'

sample flow
[image]

Comment: What’s the error?!?

Comment: Save it where?!? Where are you downloading it from? When you say “I tried to save the response as test.pdf” what exactly are you saving? The entire response or just the content? Can you show more of your flow? Hard to help at the minute.

Comment: Can you peek the code for the create file step and paste the text here or in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Got it working with below has small issue with one braces.

@{xpath(xml(outputs('createreportxml')),'string(/ServiceResponse/data/Report/id/text())')}